# EM based media queries not applying on Android browser v4.3

Tags: android, css, media-queries, mobile-devices

I am on a project that, when opened from a mobile device (in my case Android Browser 4.3), does not apply media queries.

To simplify the problem and show it on here, I have created a [super simple ONLINE DEMO](http://germanalvarez.net/5/laboratory2.html) with just this code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
      <title>EM TESTER</title>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1,  minimum-scale=1, user-scalable=yes">
   <style>

      body{background-color: yellow;}

      @media screen and (max-width: 25em) {
         body{background-color:red;}
   </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div style="font-size:300%;">25 EM TESTER</div>
   </body>
</html>
```

When I open this from my mobile, it should have red background as it is less than 25 em width, but it does not apply this.

This works properly on Chrome on my Android, **but not from my Android browser 4.3.** I have tested this on almost 10 devices, and all work properly (having background color red), even on other Android Browser versions.

Is there any known bug about this?

If I set media queries with PX instead of EM, it applies correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different browsers/devices have different issues, and mobile browsers are especially buggy.  Is it just your phone or all android devices?  It is probably just an issue related specifically to that browser or device.  Test on other mobile browsers and see what browsers have the issue.  Narrow it down and then you can start looking at a more specific problem.  Also, double check your mobile browser screen width, that can be confusing sometimes.

Comment: After checking other devices, it seems a f***king buf of my browser: all mobile devices show a red background. Mine, yelloy. I'll update with browser version info

Comment: Sometimes you just have to deal with some browsers displaying things different. Since it is only on android coupled with your specific device, that means it is a very small percent of the market.  I would just work around it. Designing for the web means making exceptions.

Comment: I agree, thats what decided yesterday. So annoying how Android browser does not care about updating new features, just chjecking for some info on the net, this browser seems to be the worst current browser (even Widows phone browser is better...). Why dont they just preinstall Chrome on all Android devices instead of this crappy thing? Well, thank you shadw

Comment: I use chrome, everything sincs

Comment: Me too but many people on Android do not even know theres a mobile Chrome version. They see the Internet icon and thats their unique app to navigate, so I was worried about not having this available for them. But after testing, both on newer and older Android browser versions this works properly, so it must be an specific issue with my phone / model / whatever